# Can you store input data or other types of data in a C++ desktop application in a file besides a text file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io, desktop-application

I'm working on a program that receives some data from the user, and also receives vital data that I define. My question is very basic and simple: is there any other kind of file that can store data?

For example, I can write Hello to a text file, then retrieve the string in that text file with my code. Is there a way I can retrieve data from another type of file the way I'd do it with a text file? I need to do this so the user can't easily access the data. After all, any windows user knows how to modify a string from a text file.

Additional details, in case you need them:
-I'm doing it in Visual Studio C++ 2010;
-Operating system is Windows XP professional;

Please tell me if you need any additional details and they will be added.

Comment: You can write anything you like in any format you like to a file (with any extension you fancy).

Comment: To be honest, you should probably get more practice writing programs for your own use before you start worrying about other users.  This question reveals that your understanding of computers and programming is still very shallow.

Answer (score 3):

You can write any kind of binary data to a file. For instance, have a `struct` which contains all your settings as booleans, then use `fwrite` to dump it to a file and `fread` to read it. This won't help you against users with a hex editor, but is probably the easiest way to store something.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a binary format. Well known text formats include `XML`.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Other techniques you could employe is encode the text in base64 encoding. If it's confidential information, you'll need to look at encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - any file can store directly any byte-aligned data.  If you want additional security, look at encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obscure data from a casual intruder, just use whatever file format you're otherwise comfortable with, and use a compression library like `zlib` to read and write the stream. For better security, use encryption instead. Existing binary formats aren't really supposed to obscure data, and inventing your own is rarely a good idea.

Comment: "inventing your own is rarely a good idea." - Whoops, guess I've been doing that wrong for the last 15 years then... ;-)

Comment: @Benj Obviously there might be perfectly valid reasons to roll your own binary file format. But if you do you should be able to answer the question "what's the advantage over using XML or JSON or Protocol Buffers or ASN.1 or a SQLite DB file?" And "to weakly obscure my data" isn't a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an XML file or an INI file.

Comment: They are text files in the technical sense. But as far I had understood the question, text files only refers to *.txt files. Reading again, you are right, he wants to make it less accessible not more.